# How to pass all values of csv file in a single request body data in JMeter?

Tags: performance-testing

I have multiple values in my JMeter request body data & I'm trying to make use of csv to pass these from a csv file in to the sampler request.Kindly help me.

I tried csv config file it did not work. I need all values of csv to be passed for a single request at once.Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

With default [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) of [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) `All Threads` each virtual user will read next line from the CSV file on each iteration. If you want to send all the data using CSV Data Set Config - make sure that everything is in one line and the line doesn't contain [delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values) character.

Other options include:

- [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function which reads the file from the file system and returns its content
- [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function where you have full control regarding which column to read and when to proceed to the next row
- [__StringFromFile()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) function which reads the next line from the file each time it's being called